# How to check if string Starts with an S, is alpha numeric and has a length of 8?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-core

I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do this.  I'm looking for a way to check the following when importing a csv:

1. String Starts with S
2. String is alpha numeric
3. Sting has a length of 8

So far I have this:

```
$Sites = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new()
Import-Csv "O:\import.csv" | `
    ForEach-Object {
        If($_.Site -match '^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$' -And $_.Site -like "S*" ) {
            [void]$Sites.Add($_.Site)
        }
    }
```

Having trouble adding the length part and I'm sure there is a cleaner way to combine all?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The following uses multiple operations, which allows for short-circuiting and therefore only applies regex-matching when necessary:

```
$_.Site[0] -ceq 'S' -and $_.Site.Length -eq 8 -and $_.Site -notmatch '[^a-z0-9]'
```

If you wanted to do it with a single regex:

```
$_.Site -cmatch '^S[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}$'
```

- For an explanation of the regex and the option to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/zcIcxc/1).

---

Note:

- Both solutions assume that only an *uppercase* `S` should be matched:

  - In the multiple-operation solution:

    - `-ceq` is used, because it is the case-*sensitive* variant of the [`-eq`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-eq), the equality-comparison operator.
    - To match `s` (lowercase) too, use `-eq` instead of `-ceq`
  - In the regex-only solution:

    - `-cmatch`, the case-*sensitive* variant of the [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operator is used
    - To match `s` (lowercase) too, you can simplify to:

      ```
      $_.Site -match '^s[a-z0-9]{7}$'
      ```
- For the sake of *performance*, using the separate-operations solution is probably not worth it (especially if you expect *most* of the inputs to match), but it is arguably *more readable* than the regex-only solution (at least to those less familiar with [regexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)).
- The above solutions only match *English* (ASCII-range) letters.